# First time compiling Java.jar on a OSX. Where should my relative paths be?

Tags: java, macos, sh, classnotfoundexception

I'm running the following command in both a bash and a sh shell :

```
#!/bin/sh
export GPU_USE_SYNC_OBJECTS=1
cd $(dirname ${0})
exec java -Xmx32m -cp target/libs/*:target/DiabloMiner.jar -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.library.path=target/libs/natives com.diablominer.DiabloMiner.DiabloMiner $@
```

I also get the following output

```
sh-3.2$ sudo ./Diablominer-osx.sh
Password:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/diablominer/DiabloMiner/DiabloMiner
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.diablominer.DiabloMiner.DiabloMiner
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
sh-3.2$
```

It appears to me that it wants to see the file in the directory `com/diablominer/DiabloMiner/DiabloMiner` so I moved the SH file above into the parent of `.com/` and I get the same error.

The [GIT source is here.](https://github.com/Diablo-D3/DiabloMiner/tree/master/src/main/java/com/diablominer) and I'm compiling on OSX Mountain Lion.

Any guidance would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a backslash in front of the `*` in that classpath:

```
-cp target/libs/\*:target/DiabloMiner.jar
```

The star needs to make it through literally into the `java` command, and not get expanded by the shell first.